# How can I use awk to only print values in a given row of file1 if they match with a list in column 1 in file2?

Tags: bash, awk

I need to remove items after the second column of file1 if they are not in a list of items in file2, which is just 1 column. Space delimiters are used.

```
$ cat file1
ID1 item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 
ID2 item4
ID3 item1 item5 item6
ID4 item2 item3

$ cat file2
item1
item3 
item6
```

Desired Output:

```
ID1 item1 item3 item6
ID2
ID3 item1 item6
ID4 item3
```

I have tried all day with multiple codes to get this to work. The one that seems the simplest is here:

```
awk -F'[ ]' '
{
    s = $1
    seen[$1]++
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
            if ($1 in seen[$i]) s = s " " $i
    print s
    delete seen
}
' file1 file2
```

I just end up with:

```
awk: cmd. line:6: (FILENAME=output6.o FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use a scalar value as array
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case I find that `keep items` is a bit easier to code than `remove items`, eg:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { keep[$1]; next }
        { out=$1
          for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
              if ($i in keep)
                 out=out OFS $i
          print out
        }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
ID1 item1 item3 item6
ID2
ID3 item1 item6
ID4 item3
```

Comment: When I use this function, it only prints the first column in file1.

Comment: I cut-n-pasted the data from your question and the code works, which means either a) you're not running the same exact code I've posted or b) your data file does not match what we see; guessing `b` ... do you by any chance have DOS line endings (`\r\n`) in your file? what does `head -2 file1 | od -c` and `head -2 file2 | od -c` show ... do you see any `\r` characters in the `od -c` output?

Comment: Yes, there are \r and \n instances, but I have in my code to remove the \r instances before we get to this part. There are \n instances at new lines.

Comment: consider running the following: `head -4 file1 | base64 > file1.b64` and `head -4 file2 | base64 > file2.b64`, then cut-n-paste the results of `cat file1.b64` and `cat file2.b64` into the question; with this new data we should be able to run `base64 -d` in our environment to give us an exact copy of (the 1st 4 lines of) your files

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach that only stores records from `file2` and simply loops over fields in `file1` comparing contents from field-2 on could be:

```bash
awk '
  NR == FNR {
    a[$1] = 1
    next
  }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (i < 2 || $i in a)
        printf "%s%s", (i>1) ? OFS : "", $i
    } 
    print ""
  }
' file2 file1
```

**Example Output**

```
ID1 item1 item3 item6
ID2
ID3 item1 item6
ID4 item3
```

Comment: How does `printf "%s%s", (i>1) ? OFS : "", $i` work? All I understand is %s is next available string and ? means that it can only work one time to match something. The output file separator does something there but not sure.

Comment: Oh, `(condition) ? if_true_clause : if_false_clause` is a *ternary* operator and is a short-hand `if .. else ...` So here is says if field greater than `1` output `OFS` (a space by default) for the first `%s` and if not (field is `1`) just output an empty-string `""` so nothing is output. (that prevents a separator before the 1st field in the output) A *ternary* is handy in many, many situations if you don't want a full `if ... else ...` You get slight optimization by using `i > 1` instead of `i == 1` because `i > 1` will be the most common branch.

Comment: You could remove that `if (...)` and ternary and do the same thing by replacing it with `if ($i in a) printf " %s", $i else if (i == 1) printf "%s", $i`. Completely up to you. I doubt you would see any performance differences -- but I would have to check on large (million record plus) files. `awk` can be crafty with optimizations.

Comment: I've tried for at least an hour to fix it, but it only prints the first line of file1.
`awk '
  NR == FNR {
    a[$1] = 1
    next
  }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (i < 2 || $i in a)
        printf "%s%s", (i>1) ? OFS : "", $i
    } 
    print ""
  }
' recordList.txt output6.o &> output7.o`

Comment: `awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = 1; next } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i in a) printf " %s", $i; else if (i == 1) printf "%s", $i } print "" }' file2 file1` --OR-- `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=1;next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (i < 2 || $i in a) printf "%s%s", (i>1)?OFS:"",$i} print ""}' file2 file1` (using the ternary)

Comment: @quantumDog in your long string, you are missing `';'` after `a[$1] = 1` in the first rule. Then `recordList.txt output6.o > output7.o`. There is no need for `&> output7.o`, that will only add redirecting `stderr` to the output file -- which is not what you would typically want.

Comment: This gets me closer. It will print only the IDs, but when it finds the first one that matches, it no longer eliminates the ones that do not and just prints them all.

Comment: How about editing the question and **adding** your current version at the end (don't change the original question -- or the answers and comments will no longer make sense) But it is fine to add to your question -- OR -- if it is really a distinctly new question, you can post it that way.  (I suspect a simple addition is what is needed). When you do, drop a comment and I'll take a look. It will be in about 8-10 hours, 500 mile drive and eyes are closing `:)`